# Bold annotations and tick labels in polar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm plotting polar scatter plots in matplotlib, with annotations near each data point.

I need to make the annotations bold (since they overlap), and also make the r axis tick labels bold (and axis label on the right of the vertical line).

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

month = ['Feb-16','Mar-16', 'Apr-16', 'May-16', 'Jun-16', 'Jul-16',
        'Aug-16', 'Sep-16', 'Nov-16', 'Dec-16', 'Jan-17']
phi = np.array([3.272, 3.185, 3.159, 2.13, 2.879, 2.617, 2.705, 
                2.53, 3.228, 3.054, np.pi]) 
r = np.array([1006.225, 1006.083, 1007.189, 1007.0614, 1002.909, 1001.053, 
              1001.953, 1006.609, 1011.403, 1013.885,1013.391])




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(phi, r, alpha=0.75)
ax.set_ylim(1000,1014)
ax.set_xlim(np.pi/2,(7/6.)*np.pi)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
for i in range(len(r)): 
    ax.annotate(month[i],
            xy=(phi[i], r[i]))
lines, labels = ax.set_thetagrids( range(90,240,30),
                           ('12:00', '11:00', '10:00','9:00', '8:00'),
                           fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems the aim is to make *everything* bold. This is easily achieved via [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams):

```
plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
```

[image]

To control the fontweight of the annotations alone, you'd use the `fontweight` argument

```
ax.annotate(..., fontweight="bold")
```

To control the fontweight of the y ticklabels you could previously do

```
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontweight="bold")
```

This however does not work in matplotlib 2.2 any more. I currently have no idea what the alternative would be (or if it's possible at all).

If you had a complete circular plot (i.e. if you left out the `xlim` here) you could also use `set_rgrids` like

```
ax.set_rgrids(range(1000,1014,2),range(1000,1014,2), fontweight="bold")
```

but that seems to be ignored for wedged plots.

Comment: Thank you, but how I control each of them separately?